# Calling Script Remotely Does Not Work

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I can run this script perfectly on my SharePoint server, and the user's profile picture gets updated:

```
[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint")
[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.Office.Server")

$siteurl = "http://SHAREPOINTSITE/"
try {
    $site = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite($siteurl)
} catch { 
    New-Item -ItemType File -Path C:\Users\admin\Desktop -Name ERROR1.txt -Value $_.Exception.Message -Force
}
try {
    $context = [Microsoft.Office.Server.ServerContext]::GetContext($site)
} catch { 
    New-Item -ItemType File -Path C:\Users\admin\Desktop -Name ERROR2.txt -Value $_.Exception.Message -Force
}

#This gets the User Profile Manager which is what we want to get hold of the users
$upm = New-Object Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.UserProfileManager($context)
$user = "DOMAIN\user.name"

#Put it in a loop for iterating for all users
if ($upm.UserExists($user)) {
    try {
        $profile = $upm.GetUserProfile($user)
        $profile["PictureURL"].Value = "\\Sharepoint\C$\Users\admin\Desktop\1.jpg";
        $profile.Commit();
    } catch {
        New-Item -ItemType File -Path C:\Users\admin\Desktop -Name ERROR3.txt -Value $_.Exception.Message -Force
    }
}

New-Item -ItemType File -Path C:\Users\admin\Desktop -Name HELLO.txt -Force

$site.Dispose()
```

But when I run it from a remote PowerShell session, I am getting some weird errors:

**ERROR1.txt**

> Exception calling ".ctor" with "1" argument(s): "The Web application at http://SHAREPOINTSITE/ could not be found. Verify that you have typed the URL correctly. If the URL should be serving existing content, the system administrator may need to add a new request URL mapping to the intended application."

**ERROR2.txt**

> Multiple ambiguous overloads found for "GetContext" and the argument count: "1".

I have checked all of the possibilities [here](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/stefan_gossner/2011/09/18/common-issue-new-spsite-api-call-returns-the-web-application-at-httpserverport-could-not-be-found/), but still seeing this issue.

This is how I call the above script from the remote machine:

```
$spfarm = "DOMAIN\admin.username"
$spfarmpw = ConvertTo-SecureString "password123" -AsPlainText -Force

$cred = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $spfarm,$spfarmpw
$session = New-PSSession SharePoint -Authentication Default -Credential $cred

Invoke-Command -Session $session -FilePath "\\SharePoint\C$\Users\admin\Desktop\testremote.ps1"
```

I have tried calling this in a few different ways (e.g. hosting the script on my machine or hosting it on the SharePoint server, as well as using relative paths to call the script), but I always see these errors.

Can anyone please help me understand why this doesn't work when calling it from a remote PC? The script is clearly being called (`HELLO.txt` always gets created), but the SharePoint profile picture never gets updated - even though that script definitely should work.

Any help or guidance is much appreciated

---

**nslookup**

```
nslookup SHAREPOINTSITE
```

**Output**

```
Server:    dc1.domain.co.uk
Address:   xx.xx.x.xx

Name:      sharepoint.domain.co.uk
Address:   yy.yy.y.yy
Aliases:   SHAREPOINTSITE.domain.co.uk
```

Where `yy.yy.y.yy` is the correct IP (it's the same address I see when executing `ping SHAREPOINTSITE`)

Comment: Does the name SHAREPOINTSITE resolve to the correct IP when you do an nslookup on the sharepoint server?

Comment: @MikeGaruccio Yes Mike I think so. I updated my answer with `nslookup` results

Comment: hmm ok, and hitting  http://SHAREPOINTSITE/ from a browser correctly displays the site correct?

Comment: @MikeGaruccio Yes, that is how users access the site and this is visible from both the server and my client machine

Comment: Invoking `New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite` will only work from one of the servers running the SharePoint farm on which the desired site resides, so don't bother testing the script from your local machine.

Comment: Are you sure you don't need the domain on your URL?

Comment: @Thriggle But the script should be running in the context of my `SharePoint` server. Do you mean to say that what I am trying to do is impossible?

Comment: @Thriggle I tried adding the domain, but this shouldn't be necessary, as the script runs perfectly on the server. Since I am calling the script from inside a remote session on that server, surely it shouldn't need any amendments, or is that wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the Authentication method to CredSSP.  This is required by the remote PowerShell so that it can pass the credentials on.